# How can I predict the outputs using a prediction function?

Tags: python

I've created my own prediction function (`R=C^3+Z^2+3`) to predict my target variable. The problem is now I am dealing with a *prediction function* not an algorithm; therefore `.predict` from scikit-learn won't work. But then how can I get my predictions?

```
def objective(C, Z) 
  return C**3 + Z**2 + 3
```

Comment: what is R ? are u trying to pass a pandas dataframe to your objective function and creating a new column for that  ?

Comment: @AminS Thanks. Yes, this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: You are expecting two variables returned but your function only returns one. What are you expecting returned?

Comment: @artemis Thanks. I am expecting "R" to be returned, which is my output.

Comment: What's `.predict`? Is that a method from some library? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you want in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

def objective(C, Z):
    return C**3 + Z**2 + 3

data = {'C': [1,2,3], 'Z': [4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['R'] = df.apply(lambda x: objective(x.C, x.Z), axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
   C  Z   R
0  1  4  20
1  2  5  36
2  3  6  66
```

Comment: Thank you @AminS and thanks to everyone else.